# Using let() standard function to return a string

Tags: kotlin

```
kotlin 1.2.31
```

I have the following function where I an trying to return a string from a `let` function.

However, the following returns `kotlin.unit` as the text

```
fun replaceSpace(quote: String, ch: Char): String {
    return quote.toCharArray().let {
        for (i in it.indices) {
            if(it[i] == ' ') {
                it[i] = ch
            }
        }
    }.toString()
}
```

I would have thought having the `toString()` would return a string but I get `kotlin.unit`

However, when I do the following it works ok. As the `String(it)` coverts the charArray to a string. As its the last statement in the `let` block that is what will be return. However, I am wondering why the `toString()` method doesn't work

```
fun replaceSpace(quote: String, ch: Char): String {
    return quote.toCharArray().let {
        for (i in it.indices) {
            if(it[i] == ' ') {
                it[i] = ch
            }
        }
        String(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: The toString() doesn't work because the last expression you have inside the let block is the for loop, and its type is Unit. So you're calling toString() on a Unit. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#returning-a-value-from-a-lambda-expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [Kotlin's let documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) you will see that the `let` function returns whatever the function you are passing to it returns. In your case, since the for doesn't return and there is no return statement, you are not returning anything inside the let function, therefore, the let will return a Unit. Since you are applying `toString` on the return of the `let` function, you will be applying `toString` on `Unit`, which is obviously not what you want.

At the same time, what you're trying to achieve (replace all spaces with a given character) can be achieved by using only Kotlin standard functions. If you take a look at the [String Kotlin's documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/index.html) you will see there is a replace function you can use that will basically help you achieve what you want.

```
quote.replace(' ', ch)
```

I also recommend you to read about `let`, `also`, `apply`, `run` and `with` in this [fantastic](https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84) article.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to replace all of the instances of one Char in a String with another Char, you can use the [`String.replace()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html#replace) extension, which is part of the Kotlin standard library:

```
quote.replace(' ', ch)
```

There shouldn't be a need to do any conversions to Strings, CharArrays, or anything else. I wouldn't even define a function to encapsulate this, you can probably drop `replaceSpace` entirely.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behaviour is that `for` is not an expression.

But the whole logic of this question is quite convoluted.

This whole function could be replace with:

```
fun replaceSpace(quote: String, ch: Char) = quote.replace(" ", ch.toString())
```